# php pagination querying multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data from 6 different tables and use pagination so the user can scroll through the items similar to a shopping site.

I am using the following code to display a field called request id from a table call request (as a test) in pages of 10 which works fine.

```
<?php
include('connect.php'); 
$targetpage = "page.php";    
$limit = 10; 

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM request";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$stages = 3;
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);
if($page){
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
}else{
$start = 0; 
    }       
// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM request LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($query1);

// Initial page num setup
if ($page == 0){$page = 1;}
$prev = $page - 1;  
$next = $page + 1;                          
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
$LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;                    

$paginate = '';
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
$paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
// Previous
if ($page > 1){
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";   }

// Pages    
if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2))  // Not enough pages to breaking it up
{   
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page){
$paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
}
}
elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2))   // Enough pages to hide a few?
{
// Beginning only hide later pages
if($page < 1 + ($stages * 2))       
{
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page){
$paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
}
$paginate.= "...";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
}
// Middle hide some front and some back
elseif($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2))
{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";                          
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
$paginate.= "...";
for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page){
$paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>"; 
}else{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
}
$paginate.= "...";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";       
}
// End only hide early pages
else
{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
$paginate.= "...";
for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page){
$paginate.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";}                    
}
}
}
// Next
if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
$paginate.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
}else{
$paginate.= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
}
$paginate.= "</div>";       
}
echo $total_pages.' Results';
// pagination
echo $paginate;
?>
<ul>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{       
echo '<li>'.$row['requestid'].'</li>';
}
?>
```

I am now trying to display the data from a total of 6 tables using the following query and it doesn't work?

I don't think I have used the COUNT command correctly in the query?

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT as num r.*, m.*, u.*, a.*, i.*, b.*, r.*
FROM request r INNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.movieid 
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.actorid 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = r.userid
INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.itemid
INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandid = r.brandid
WHERE gender = 'male'";
```

Comment: please describe in text what you are trying to count. Your current query would return only requests with at least one movie,  with at least one actor, at least one user, at least one item, at least one brand, and where the gender (of the user? the actor?) is male.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use the `COUNT` feature, you have to specify what you're counting.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num r.*, m.*, u.*, a.*, i.*, b.*, r.*
FROM request r INNER JOIN movie m ON m.movieid = r.movieid 
INNER JOIN actor a ON a.actorid = r.actorid 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = r.userid
INNER JOIN item i ON i.itemid = r.itemid
INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandid = r.brandid
WHERE gender = 'male'";
```

Comment: That will probably return `1` as `num` for each row, since he's also selecting everything else. Problem is, the question is not clear enough.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, I was showing how to use the count function.

Comment: When I change the query to the above I get an error saying "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ********** styles.php on line 46

Comment: That's because (if I'm not mistaken) the output of the query is not a MySQL resource, it's the number of selected rows.

Comment: OK so how do I output as a MySQL resource so I can pull the data from the 6 tables and not just the number of rows?

Comment: Remove the `COUNT()` and count the returned rows instead using PHP's count() function, that way you have both rows and number of rows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3801/discussion-between-martin-dye-and-korvin-szanto)